# Noob Question: IIS7, how do I add myself as a user?

Tags: iis-7, permissions, users

I'm using the Windows 7 evaluation version, and I just setup the IIS7 Server by going into the Add/Remove Programs section and adding IIS. I'm trying to play with ASP a little bit and learn about it, but when I go to edit any of the files in the Inetpub/wwwroot directory, I can't edit anything because I do not have permission.

Also, I can access the IIS Manager but I'm not sure how to add myself as a user, correctly, so I can start editing and creating files. Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

not sure if this works in iis7 vs iis6 but windows explorer is where you need to go in and add the user to have permission to the wwwroot folder.

Comment: haha, yeah, I just found that information on a website a little bit ago. I have it working now. Thank you though.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, for anyone that needs to know. Here's the answer:

You have to do folder sharing through the properties dialog for the wwwroot folder in Windows 7 RC. It worked for me right after that. That's it. Thanks everyone.